# VQE on Qiskit: getting counts per Hamiltonian term

Tags: qiskit, vqe, qasm

Consider a VQE calculation (using the QASM backend and on Qiskit) that involves a qubit Hamiltonian with, say, 5 terms. Is there a way for us to get the counts for each of the Hamiltonian terms that are measured, and is it possible to get this info for each iteration? Thanks in advance!